# Inserting into an index position in a List

Tags: c#, list, insert

I'm trying to overwrite a value in a `List` using Insert, but My results are not ask expected.

After I run the code I have 6 values in the `List`, but there should only be 4

Test:

```
 public class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ModuleCAResults results = new ModuleCAResults() { modName = "Databases", credits = 5, name ="John" };
            results[1] = 100;
            results[2] = 50;
            results[3] = 89;
            results[1] = 40;
            results[3] = 20;
            results[4] = 6;

            Console.WriteLine(results);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Class

```
public class ModuleCAResults
{
    public string modName { get; set; }
    public int credits { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    List<double> scores = new List<double>();

    public override String ToString()
    {
        string output = "Modual Name: " + modName + ", Credits: " + credits + ", Name: " + name + "\nCA Resulst:\n";
        for(int i =0; i< scores.Count; i++)
        {
            output += scores[i] + "\n";
        }
        return output;
    }


    public double this[int i]
    {

        get
        {
            int index = i - 1;
            if (index < 0 || index > scores.Count)
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid CA number get");
            }
            else
                return scores[i]; 
        }
        set
        {
            int index = i - 1;
            if (index < 0 || index > scores.Count)
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid CA number set");
            }
            else
            { 
                    scores.Insert(index, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried a few different ways now, but can't solve the problem.

Comment: What are you doing looks to me more like a `Dictionary<int, double>` rather than list behavior

Comment: `Insert` will **add** the value at the index, not overwrite the value at the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your indexer should be like this

```
public double this[int i]
{  
    get
    {
        int index = i - 1;
        if (index < 0 || index >= scores.Count)
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid CA number get");
        }
        else
            return scores[i]; 
    }
    set
    {
        int index = i - 1;
        if (index < 0 || index > scores.Count)
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid CA number set");
        }
        else
        { 
            if (index < scores.Count)
                scores[index] = value;
            else
                scores.Add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you, I'm going to review my code now and see where I went wrong, besides misunderstanding the Insert method, I had something very similar to this.

Comment: Misunderstanding the Insert method was the route of my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`Insert` doesn't overwrite, it inserts at the index and "pushes" everything an index over. So when you're inserting at index `2`, it adds the item to the list, and pushes what was at index `2` to index `3`, and what was at `3` to `4`, and so on.

Instead, you can use a combination of `Add` and indexing into the list to accomplish what you want:

```
if(scores.Count < index)
{
    //If the index you're accessing is past the end of the list, use Add
    scores.Add(value);
}
else
{
    //Otherwise let's overwrite what's already at index i
    scores[index] = value;
}
```

Comment: I had something similar to your code and I was getting Index was out of range errors, I just plugged in your code and still same problem, not sure why I'm getting out of range.

Answer (score 1):

List.Insert method inserts new item at the specified position. It will not replace original element at this position.

So this code:

```
scores.Insert(index, value);
```

just inserts new value at index position moving all other values in the list one position further.

To have only 4 elements replace it with the assignment by index:

```
scores[index] = value;
```

Comment: This will fail with an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when you attempt to add the first item.

Comment: This will not fail for the example in the question. I didn't make any suggestions about algorithm, just specified a tool.

Answer (score 1):

The Insert method on the List class will insert the item at the end when index is equal to the number of items in the list.
For more information on what is going wrong, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The best answer so far is the one provided by http://stackoverflow.com/users/1630665/dave-zych